# Creation of a two level hash in Ruby with certain conditions while querying

Tags: ruby, jrubyonrails

I created a two level hash in Ruby where the value at second level must have an array

```
sampleHash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new{|a,b| a[b] = [] }}
```

However, while querying for values whose keys doesn't exist ,eg -

```
sampleHash[x][y] == [] #check if it doesnt have anything
sampleHash[x][y].length == 0 #check if it doesnt have anything
```

it creates an entry

```
puts sampleHash[x][y]
>>>> []
```

How do I prevent this?

Note - JRuby on Rails has another problem where it is creating a duplicate key. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are explicitly stating that, when any key is checked, an array is created if need be.

The only way (I can see right now) to prevent this is by not submitting default values for your inner Hash :

```
sampleHash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
```

And do the heavy lifting from there.

#### edit: result

```
sampleHash['x'] # => {}
sampleHash['x']['y'] # => nil
```

You can also keep your original code (from [Heidar B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4770080/heidar-b)) :

Always make sure to use `has_key?` to check if any values are set because every time you reference the value of a hash key it creates the default value you specified in the Hash constructor.

For that reason you can keep your original code and use `has_key?` to check both levels of the hash before using any of the keys/values, otherwise you may end up with many useless objects!

**EDIT**  - The reason for duplicate keys is something to do with the fact that Java has problems when the keys are primitives

Comment: Heavy lifting ? As in ?U mean to say I check if second level key exists or not using has_key? ?

Comment: Also, im getting a weird error where it created a duplicate key - only in JRuby1.7.2 on Rails

Comment: maybe heavy lifting is not the right word : you'll have to initialize your arrays before using them. I can't answer about JRuby, I have never tried it yet.

Comment: so yea - using has_key then. If no second level key - then initialize empty array. else - just push

Comment: It did! Also - i discovered that there is a problem with using primitives as keys in second level hash - something common to NodeJS and JRuby (all java based stuff)